# How use libtorrent for python to get info_hash

Tags: python, libtorrent

```
from libtorrent as lt
info = lt.torrent_info(open('example.torrent','rb').read())
info.info_hash()
```

This doesn't get the hash, instead I get the object `<libtorrent.big_number object at ...... >`

What should I do?

Comment: Please give more information about what you tried - otherwise this question will be closed.

Comment: info_hash() returns an *object*. There is most likely a method to access the hash in a hexadecimal form.

Answer (score 8):

The existing answers give you everything you need ... but here's some code to make it explicit:

```
import libtorrent as lt
info = lt.torrent_info(open('example.torrent','rb').read())
info_hash = info.info_hash()
hexadecimal = str(info_hash)
integer = int(hexadecimal, 16)
```

**EDIT**: Actually, that's wrong - `torrent_info()` should be passed the length of the torrent file as well as its content. Revised (working) version:

```
import libtorrent as lt
torrent = open('example.torrent','rb').read()
info = lt.torrent_info(torrent, len(torrent))
info_hash = info.info_hash()
hexadecimal = str(info_hash)
integer = int(hexadecimal, 16)
```

Comment: And what I needed was just `print hexadecimal`. Good!

Comment: @zero-piraeus How do I solve the unicode-decode error? For example, I am getting error like `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc`.....How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html#torrent-info

```
info_hash() returns the 20-bytes sha1-hash for the info-section of the torrent file. 
For more information on the sha1_hash, see the [big_number] class.
```

So http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html#big-number

Just iterate over the bytes and you have your hash.

Answer (score -2):

Just call `str(info.info_hash())`.

Edit: actually `str` is not correct. But what be the correct way to write out the hex string?